Does moisture between concrete floor and 6-mil poly eventually reabsorb into concrete?
When installing various flooring products on a below-grade concrete floor, flooring manufacturers often require placing a 6-mil polyethylene barrier directly onto the floor.  Possible underlayment and then flooring go atop the 6-mil.
Assuming that it's a relatively dry situation, one would still expect some (hopefully small) amount of moisture to come up through the concrete and become trapped between the concrete and the 6-mil. Is it reasonable to assume that as seasons/exterior conditions change, that same moisture will eventually re-absorb into the concrete and return to the ground?
A comment on this question suggests that this is the case, but I wanted to ask specifically about this potentially-trapped moisture, as it seems it would be an unfortunate situation to have moisture permanently trapped between the concrete and the poly.
